# Adding jquery library in Orchard

Tags: jquery, orchardcms

I'm building a module that doesn't have any views, but inserts some javascript in all pages. This javascript requires JQuery. For this I want to instruct Orchard that it needs to load the jquery module. I found some ways to do that but all of them go in the view.

Is there a way to tell orchard to load the jquery library, from a controller, or better yet from a FilterProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in your module make **ResourceManifest.cs**

```
using Orchard.UI.Resources;

public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider
{
    public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {
        var manifest = builder.Add();

        manifest.DefineScript("MyScript")
            .SetUrl("myscript.min.js", "myscript.js") // Or just use one
            .SetVersion("1.0.0")
            .SetDependencies("jQuery");
    }
}
```

Then just include `MyScript` with resource manager in your `FilterProvider`

```
public class MyScriptFilter : FilterProvider, IResultFilter 
{
    private readonly IResourceManager resourceManager;

    public MyScriptFilter(IResourceManager resourceManager) 
    {
        this.resourceManager = resourceManager;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {
        if (!(filterContext.Result is ViewResult) || !UI.Admin.AdminFilter.IsApplied(filterContext.RequestContext))
        {
            // Control where when it should and shouldn't appear, like exclude admin and any non-ViewResult
            return;
        }

        this.resourceManager.Require("script", "MyScript");
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) 
    {
    }
}
```

Haven't tested this so not sure if it compiles, but it should do the trick.

Comment: While the solution will work, and in particular, the way to declare script that depends on jQuery is exactly right, including script usually belongs in the view, so i wouldn't necessarily recommend the second part of the answer: what if a site author wants to replace the view with another one that uses a different script, in his theme?

Comment: You could simply include the Resource on the Layout : Script.Require("MyScript");